# jQuery UI Dialog - animations

Tags: jquery-ui

Is it possible to use built-in jQuery animations for use with a Dialog? I tried:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    modal: true,
    height: 500,
    width: 550,
    show: 'fadeIn',
    hide: 'fadeOut'
});
```

But this does not work. The only way I can seem to get animations to work is by including the jQuery UI animations pack, which results in a larger file.

Comment: You have an extra comma after `hide: 'fadeOut',`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
modal: true,
height: 500,
width: 550,
show: 'fade',
hide: 'fade',
});
```

The fadien and fadeout are independent methods. You can only use those options which you use with show and hide functions

Comment: That does not give the fade effect either.

Comment: I want to know how to make it work using the standard 'fade' effect included in jQuery, not the one included in jQuery UI.

Comment: This does the same thing i.e reduces the opacity in steps. If you are adamant on using fadein and fadeout, u need extra code.  Check this update http://jsfiddle.net/MqEqJ/1/